# Альтернатива finalize

Tags: java, java-8, сборщик-мусора

У меня есть класс. При уничтожении его объекта он должен выполнить некоторые действия. Для этого есть метод finalize, но его вызов не гарантируется сборщиком мусора. Есть ли какие-либо альтернативные способы автоматически выполнить необходимые действия при уничтожении объекта не используя finalize.

Comment: время уничтожения объекта не должно тревожить java разработчика. Либо вызывайте явно, либо используйте try-finally или перейдите на язык с детерминированным вызовом деструктора.

Comment: но меня волнует, потому что в моей задаче во время уничтожении объекта из бд должны удаляться данные

Comment: используйте интерфейс `Closeable`/`AutoCloseable` и `try-with-resources`

Comment: @БадмаБардаев удаление объекта из памяти и из базы никак не связанные между собой вещи